# MySQL distinct users table but repeating every year, to make a kind of histogram

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm blocked on this which for sure is a simple thing to do. I have a table with a list of users with date logins, example:

```
---------------------
date       | user
---------------------
2013-07-08 | Carl
2013-07-09 | Mark
2013-07-09 | Robert
2013-08-09 | Robert
2013-08-09 | Saul
2013-09-09 | Paula
2014-01-09 | Mark
2014-02-09 | Robert
```

and so.
So I do a

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user) FROM logins;
```

to get a full list of users. Now what I want is to get a result with the total count of logins (each year) of each user, and **if the user didn't log in during the past year, still add it to the results with a 0 count**. The important thing is to respect user list.

If I do this:

```
SELECT user, year(date) as year, COUNT(*) as count
FROM logins
GROUP BY user, year 
ORDER BY year ASC, count DESC;
```

I will get the right count for users logged in 2013 and 2014 and so but the ones didn't log-in will be excluded, and I need to include them with a 0 count.
No matter if the solution is MySQL, PHP or even JS. just need the array to latter on encode as JSON.
So far I tried with MySQL with no luck, and now I'm trying with PHP getting the list of users in one array and the above results in another array but also no luck on a fast way to do it or I'm lacking of ideas because my psychiatric treatment pills (yes, my head is oversaturated).
That's why I need help.

**THANKS FOR SHARING ALL YOUR KNOWLEDGE AS ALWAYS!**

**EDIT**
As asked by @Rick, here is the table in question and the real fields I'm using are "**`isp`**" and "**`fecha_login`**"

```
CREATE TABLE `login_history` (                                                           
                 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                                  
                 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                                        
                 `personal_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
                 `responsable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                                 
                 `nombre` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,          
                 `fecha_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                                                   
                 `ip` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,                                                    
                 `isp` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,            
                 `ciudad` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,          
                 `provincia` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,       
                 `pais` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,            
                 `dispositivo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,    
                 `datosmoviles` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,                                                    
                 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                                                                     
               ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20991 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and the explain select:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 19690 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 19690 | Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
| 1 | PRIMARY | l | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 19690 | Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join) |
| 3 | DERIVED | login_history | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 19690 | Using temporary |
| 2 | DERIVED | login_history | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 19690 | Using temporary |

Comment: Why use `logins` to get a unique list of users? There should already be a separate table containing unique users in your db, example: `users`. If yes, all you need is an outer join between `users` and `logins` to count logins by year.

Comment: yes but this is not the case. I used "users" as example but the kind of data is not necessary a table of usernames, let's say fixed ip addresses as another example, or domains or whatever. And making another table with just that data could be an option but trying to avoid that. I will take in consideration that anyway if no further answers solving as I wanted.

Comment: To build on SOS's comment, perhaps you could outer join a subquery from the `logins` table that groups and contains a record for each user - have you tried that?

Comment: Agreed. To include users with 0 logins, you'd need to start with some sort of subquery to obtain a unique user list.  That'll be more expensive than if there were already a table of unique users, but ... Anyway, then join outer join that query back to `logins` and count(user) by year.

Comment: I will try, to see how better performs on like.. 50k records compared with the current solution that @forpas gave. Alot of thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `CROSS` join of all the distinct years and all the distinct users and a `LEFT` join to the table so that you can have all the possible combinations before you aggregate:

```
SELECT y.year, u.user, COUNT(l.user) count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) year FROM logins) y
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM logins) u
LEFT JOIN logins l ON YEAR(l.date) = y.year AND l.user = u.user
GROUP BY y.year, u.user
ORDER BY y.year, count DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96e818c28c01001a17a728fe93c5d77f).

Comment: so far your answer works as expected.  As SOS and Andrew wrote, it's a bit more expensive but acceptable (650ms on 20k records). 
Gonna try with a separate "users" table to see how better it is.

I forgot to mention and tag the possibility of a mongo query too as resolution (because at the end, I just need a json).
Thanks @forpas !

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned performance as a problem.  This answer addresses that.

A quick fix is to build and maintain a separate table with just the users and another with just the years.  Since @forpas's query *requires at least* 3 full passes over the table, this quick fix may more than double the speed.

To get more speed (maybe 10x more), build and maintain a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) with columns for day, user, and count for that day for that user.  Then run the big query against the summary table.

If "day" does not provide enough shrinkage, pick month instead.

If you need a partial count for the current year-to-date, use the summary table for time before today (or this month), then UNION with another query to get the partial results from there forward.

If you get that far, but are not happy with the speed, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for help with indexing.

Comment: You are going way too advanced to my knowledge, but I like to learn so I book'ed that link to learn how to. This right now is a pretty basic project and (used to) learning on the road. This table is not even indexed (forgot to mention that) because is just a test. Maybe I will switch to mongo wich also I'm trying to learn about.

I will add in the main post what you asked, the table structure and explain select.
I used "date" and "user" as example because it have some spanish

Comment: @ElMauro - [_Indexing_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) is key to performance.  However it was not the main factor in this particular question.